# Stackoverflow error comes in Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-functions

I had `Azure function` which was written using `.NET Core 3.1` and suddenly stopped working and showing StackOverflow exception in below code at `TryAddEnumerables`

[image]

Here is my stack trace

[image]

[image]

My startup class

```
 builder.Services
            .AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config)
            .AddSingleton(serviceProvider => serviceProvider)
            .AddLogging()
            .AddSingleton<IManager, CManager>()
            .AddSingleton<IRegexManager, RegexManager>()
```

Removing below line solves the StackOverflow error but not sure on side affects of it

```
 AddSingleton(serviceProvider => serviceProvider)
```

Trace

System.Private.CoreLib.dll!Interop.Advapi32.EventWriteTransfer_PInvoke(long registrationHandle, System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventDescriptor eventDescriptor, System.Guid* activityId, System.Guid* relatedActivityId, int userDataCount, System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventProvider.EventData* userData) Unknown

```
 System.StackOverflowException
       HResult=0x800703E9
       Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
     StackTrace:
  <Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace
```

System.Private.CoreLib.dll!Interop.Advapi32.EventWriteTransfer(long registrationHandle, System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventDescriptor eventDescriptor, System.Guid* activityId, System.Guid* relatedActivityId, int userDataCount, System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventProvider.EventData* userData)   Unknown
System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EtwEventProvider.System.Diagnostics.Tracing.IEventProvider.EventWriteTransfer(long registrationHandle, System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventDescriptor eventDescriptor, System.IntPtr eventHandle, System.Guid* activityId, System.Guid* relatedActivityId, int userDataCount, System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventProvider.EventData* userData)   Unknown
System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventProvider.WriteEvent(ref System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventDescriptor eventDescriptor, System.IntPtr eventHandle, System.Guid* activityID, System.Guid* childActivityID, int dataCount, System.IntPtr data) Unknown
System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.WriteEventWithRelatedActivityIdCore(int eventId, System.Guid* relatedActivityId, int eventDataCount, System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.EventData* data)  Unknown
System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.TplEventSource.TraceOperationBegin(int TaskID, string OperationName, long RelatedContext) Unknown
System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.AsyncCausalityTracer.TraceOperationCreation(System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, string operationName)   Unknown
System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ScheduleAndStart(bool needsProtection)   Unknown

Comment: Don't you have a full stack trace on that exception? Preferable as text in the question, not as an image. See [ths FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) why that is.

Comment: updated the trace (partial) it's huge

Comment: One common cause or StackOverflow is infinite recursion. You can spot this in the stack trace by looking for a repetitive pattern of methods.

Comment: Is configureService re-entrant for some reason? What does that invoke do? Does that JobHostService have magic in its (static) constructor?